# What to break in KDE to disable transparency?

Tags: kde-4, transparency, kde-plasma-workspace

In KDE 4.9 one can disable the transparency of most items, but not of the Plasma Panel. However, that thing annoys me to all extent. I cannot have applications full-screened then Alt-Tab to another window as the full-screen application bleeds through the panel and I can no longer make out what is actually in the panel (such as reading the clock). Is there any file that transparency depends on that I can simply `rm` away?

Note that turning off all effects is not a solution. I use the effects for some disability issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same trouble.I can't see the text clearly. But at least you can disable "Blur",

> system-setting->desktop-effects->all-effects->Blur

Comment: Thank you. Blur was long gone, but it does not resolve this issue.

Comment: it just make the panel a little more clear. I have the same issue. So have cinnamon and kde in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Though you asked for plasma 4.9 10 years ago, I came across this issue when looking for a way to do it in plasma 5.27. So here is the answer if anyone is looking for that as well:

You can right-click on the panel, "Enter Edit Mode", "More Options", and set Opacity to Opaque there.