# Reduce visual effects in KDE Plasma?

Tags: linux, kde, opengl, kde-plasma-workspace, kde-plasma-5

**Problem**

We have a RHEL x64 machine with KDE Plasma 5+ and we don't want any fancy graphics or effects. We tried manually disabling the effects through the settings menu, but this has had little effect on removing options which cannot be adjusted. For example, there are some menu transparency effects which remain even when disabled in the settings.

**Question**

How do we fully disable all effects and make Plasma as lean and light as possible?

**Desired Outcome**

A plasma workspace without any graphical effects.

**KDE/LXDE**

The obvious long-workaround/alternative would be to install and use LXDE instead of Plasma. Prior to going to this option, we would like to determine if the desired outcome can be achieved within Plasma itself.

**Research**

A similar problem in version 4.9 [[1](https://superuser.com/questions/541516/what-to-break-in-kde-to-disable-transparency)]:

> In KDE 4.9 one can disable the transparency of most items, but not of
>   the Plasma Panel. However, that thing annoys me to all extent. I
>   cannot have applications full-screened then Alt-Tab to another window
>   as the full-screen application bleeds through the panel and I can no
>   longer make out what is actually in the panel (such as reading the
>   clock). Is there any file that transparency depends on that I can
>   simply rm away?

Comment: KDE is probably the heaviest desktop and you want to change it into a lightweight.  That probably isn't the best starting point for a lightweight desktop.  That said, there are a few distros that have largely done that, so you may be able to look at what they've done.  It's been a while since I checked out various distros.  I recall there were a couple of popular distros that had very stripped down implementations but, unfortunately, don't recall which.  You might need to look at some LiveDVDs.  PCLinux OS might have been an example, but I wouldn't bet the farm on it.

Answer (score 2):

System Settings > Display and Monitor > Compositor > Disable compositor on startup.

You can also disable them by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.